# Using RegEx to match counties in json list

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a big json file that looks like this:

```
{"state": "AL", "year": 2020, "events": [{"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 34, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 20747.0, "locations": "Franklin [AL], Limestone [AL], Colbert [AL], Jackson [AL], Madison [AL], DeKalb [AL], Lawrence [AL], Lauderdale [AL], Morgan [AL], Cullman [AL], Marshall [AL]", "issue": "2020-02-12T22:34:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-02-12T22:34:00Z", "expire": "2020-02-13T03:27:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-02-13T06:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KHUN-SV-A-0034", "wfo": "HUN"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 34, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 33422.0, "locations": "Tuscaloosa [AL], Greene [AL], Bibb [AL], Shelby [AL], Sumter [AL], Winston [AL], Cherokee [AL], Lamar [AL], Blount [AL], Etowah [AL], Walker [AL], Fayette [AL], St. Clair [AL], Marion [AL], Jefferson [AL], Pickens [AL], Hale [AL]", "issue": "2020-02-12T22:35:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-02-12T22:35:00Z", "expire": "2020-02-13T03:02:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-02-13T06:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KBMX-SV-A-0034", "wfo": "BMX"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 41, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 28974.0, "locations": "Pike [AL], Elmore [AL], Dallas [AL], Bullock [AL], Montgomery [AL], Perry [AL], Autauga [AL], Marengo [AL], Barbour [AL], Lowndes [AL], Sumter [AL], Macon [AL], Greene [AL], Hale [AL], Russell [AL]", "issue": "2020-03-04T08:39:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-03-04T08:39:00Z", "expire": "2020-03-04T14:29:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-03-04T16:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KBMX-SV-A-0041", "wfo": "BMX"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 45, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 26481.0, "locations": "Tuscaloosa [AL], Hale [AL], Walker [AL], Fayette [AL], Winston [AL], Lamar [AL], Perry [AL], Bibb [AL], Pickens [AL], Greene [AL], Marengo [AL], Marion [AL], Sumter [AL]", "issue": "2020-03-11T17:26:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-03-11T17:26:00Z", "expire": "2020-03-11T22:42:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-03-12T00:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KBMX-SV-A-0045", "wfo": "BMX"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 88, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 55154.0, "locations": "Bibb [AL], Dallas [AL], Randolph [AL], Shelby [AL], Greene [AL], Pickens [AL], Montgomery [AL], Elmore [AL], Russell [AL], Tallapoosa [AL], Perry [AL], Chambers [AL], Clay [AL], Lowndes [AL], Sumter [AL], Macon [AL], Talladega [AL], Chilton [AL], Coosa [AL], Lee [AL], Pike [AL], Marengo [AL], Barbour [AL], Tuscaloosa [AL], Autauga [AL], Jefferson [AL], Hale [AL], Bullock [AL]", "issue": "2020-04-08T19:41:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-08T19:41:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-08T23:58:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-09T02:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KBMX-SV-A-0088", "wfo": "BMX"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 88, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 16510.0, "locations": "Choctaw [AL], Clarke [AL], Butler [AL], Conecuh [AL], Crenshaw [AL], Wilcox [AL], Monroe [AL]", "issue": "2020-04-08T19:41:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-08T19:41:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-08T23:50:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-09T02:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KMOB-SV-A-0088", "wfo": "MOB"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 94, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 20747.0, "locations": "Franklin [AL], Madison [AL], Lauderdale [AL], Cullman [AL], Colbert [AL], Marshall [AL], Jackson [AL], DeKalb [AL], Morgan [AL], Lawrence [AL], Limestone [AL]", "issue": "2020-04-09T03:17:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-09T03:17:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-09T08:00:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-09T10:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KHUN-SV-A-0094", "wfo": "HUN"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 142, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 10846.0, "locations": "Clarke [AL], Wilcox [AL], Choctaw [AL], Washington [AL]", "issue": "2020-04-23T21:06:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-23T21:06:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-23T22:56:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-24T02:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KMOB-SV-A-0142", "wfo": "MOB"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 142, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 35385.0, "locations": "Perry [AL], Randolph [AL], Chambers [AL], Autauga [AL], Clay [AL], Bibb [AL], Coosa [AL], Greene [AL], Sumter [AL], Dallas [AL], Chilton [AL], Tallapoosa [AL], Shelby [AL], Elmore [AL], Talladega [AL], Hale [AL], Lee [AL], Lowndes [AL], Marengo [AL]", "issue": "2020-04-23T21:07:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-23T21:07:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-23T22:59:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-24T02:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KBMX-SV-A-0142", "wfo": "BMX"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 159, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 8458.0, "locations": "Madison [AL], Limestone [AL], Lauderdale [AL], Jackson [AL]", "issue": "2020-05-03T20:43:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-05-03T20:43:00Z", "expire": "2020-05-04T01:00:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-05-04T01:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KHUN-SV-A-0159", "wfo": "HUN"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 166, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 10475.0, "locations": "Madison [AL], Limestone [AL], Lauderdale [AL], Jackson [AL], DeKalb [AL]", "issue": "2020-05-04T23:42:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-05-04T23:42:00Z", "expire": "2020-05-05T04:00:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-05-05T05:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KHUN-SV-A-0166", "wfo": "HUN"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 300, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 14523.0, "locations": "Barbour [AL], Bullock [AL], Montgomery [AL], Lowndes [AL], Macon [AL], Russell [AL], Lee [AL], Pike [AL]", "issue": "2020-06-24T18:36:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-06-24T18:36:00Z", "expire": "2020-06-24T23:08:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-06-25T02:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KBMX-SV-A-0300", "wfo": "BMX"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 300, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 29503.0, "locations": "Monroe [AL], Mobile [AL], Wilcox [AL], Escambia [AL], Crenshaw [AL], Baldwin [AL], Conecuh [AL], Covington [AL], Butler [AL], Clarke [AL], Washington [AL]", "issue": "2020-06-24T18:36:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-06-24T18:36:00Z", "expire": "2020-06-24T23:18:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-06-25T02:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KMOB-SV-A-0300", "wfo": "MOB"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 300, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 7704.0, "locations": "Coffee [AL], Geneva [AL], Dale [AL], Henry [AL], Houston [AL]", "issue": "2020-06-24T18:40:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-06-24T18:40:00Z", "expire": "2020-06-25T00:38:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-06-25T02:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KTAE-SV-A-0300", "wfo": "TAE"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 362, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 66859.0, "locations": "Bibb [AL], Walker [AL], Elmore [AL], Pickens [AL], Fayette [AL], Chambers [AL], St. Clair [AL], Tuscaloosa [AL], Russell [AL], Tallapoosa [AL], Greene [AL], Hale [AL], Jefferson [AL], Calhoun [AL], Lamar [AL], Coosa [AL], Lee [AL], Cleburne [AL], Macon [AL], Perry [AL], Clay [AL], Sumter [AL], Lowndes [AL], Pike [AL], Barbour [AL], Autauga [AL], Marengo [AL], Randolph [AL], Bullock [AL], Montgomery [AL], Dallas [AL], Talladega [AL], Blount [AL], Shelby [AL], Chilton [AL]", "issue": "2020-07-12T17:12:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-07-12T17:12:00Z", "expire": "2020-07-12T23:29:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-07-13T00:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KBMX-SV-A-0362", "wfo": "BMX"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 364, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 7704.0, "locations": "Coffee [AL], Dale [AL], Henry [AL], Geneva [AL], Houston [AL]", "issue": "2020-07-12T20:40:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-07-12T20:40:00Z", "expire": "2020-07-13T01:46:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-07-13T03:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KTAE-SV-A-0364", "wfo": "TAE"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 364, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 31895.0, "locations": "Wilcox [AL], Clarke [AL], Baldwin [AL], Crenshaw [AL], Mobile [AL], Conecuh [AL], Choctaw [AL], Butler [AL], Covington [AL], Monroe [AL], Washington [AL], Escambia [AL]", "issue": "2020-07-12T20:41:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-07-12T20:41:00Z", "expire": "2020-07-13T03:00:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-07-13T03:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KMOB-SV-A-0364", "wfo": "MOB"}]}{"state": "AK", "year": 2020, "events": []}{"state": "AZ", "year": 2020, "events": []}{"state": "AR", "year": 2020, "events": [{"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 37, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 12735.0, "locations": "Lee [AR], St. Francis [AR], Poinsett [AR], Mississippi [AR], Craighead [AR], Cross [AR], Crittenden [AR]", "issue": "2020-03-03T07:00:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-03-03T06:59:00Z", "expire": "2020-03-03T10:12:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-03-03T11:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KMEG-SV-A-0037", "wfo": "MEG"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 108, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 4619.0, "locations": "Little River [AR], Miller [AR], Sevier [AR]", "issue": "2020-04-12T19:51:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-12T19:51:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-13T01:00:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-13T01:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KSHV-SV-A-0108", "wfo": "SHV"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 111, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 86754.0, "locations": "Monroe [AR], Prairie [AR], Baxter [AR], Hot Spring [AR], Cleburne [AR], Pulaski [AR], Lonoke [AR], Desha [AR], Perry [AR], Boone [AR], Woodruff [AR], Pike [AR], Lincoln [AR], Jackson [AR], Independence [AR], Marion [AR], Grant [AR], Pope [AR], Drew [AR], White [AR], Calhoun [AR], Dallas [AR], Arkansas [AR], Randolph [AR], Lawrence [AR], Searcy [AR], Newton [AR], Sharp [AR], Van Buren [AR], Fulton [AR], Polk [AR], Scott [AR], Montgomery [AR], Faulkner [AR], Johnson [AR], Clark [AR], Logan [AR], Cleveland [AR], Izard [AR], Stone [AR], Ouachita [AR], Yell [AR], Conway [AR], Bradley [AR], Saline [AR], Garland [AR], Jefferson [AR]", "issue": "2020-04-12T23:00:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-12T22:59:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-13T02:47:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-13T04:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KLZK-SV-A-0111", "wfo": "LZK"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 111, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 11208.0, "locations": "Howard [AR], Hempstead [AR], Nevada [AR], Union [AR], Lafayette [AR], Columbia [AR]", "issue": "2020-04-12T23:00:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-12T22:59:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-13T02:55:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-13T04:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KSHV-SV-A-0111", "wfo": "SHV"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 114, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 17781.0, "locations": "Craighead [AR], Crittenden [AR], Clay [AR], Cross [AR], Phillips [AR], Mississippi [AR], St. Francis [AR], Lee [AR], Poinsett [AR], Greene [AR]", "issue": "2020-04-13T01:20:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-13T01:19:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-13T04:50:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-13T06:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KMEG-SV-A-0114", "wfo": "MEG"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 131, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 4512.0, "locations": "Little River [AR], Sevier [AR], Howard [AR]", "issue": "2020-04-22T06:47:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-22T06:47:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-22T11:00:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-22T11:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KSHV-SV-A-0131", "wfo": "SHV"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 132, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 13161.0, "locations": "Carroll [AR], Madison [AR], Crawford [AR], Washington [AR], Franklin [AR], Benton [AR], Sebastian [AR]", "issue": "2020-04-22T13:55:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-22T13:55:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-22T20:00:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-22T20:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KTSA-SV-A-0132", "wfo": "TSA"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 145, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 13161.0, "locations": "Franklin [AR], Crawford [AR], Carroll [AR], Washington [AR], Benton [AR], Sebastian [AR], Madison [AR]", "issue": "2020-04-24T20:44:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-24T20:44:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-25T02:22:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-25T04:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KTSA-SV-A-0145", "wfo": "TSA"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 147, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 2735.0, "locations": "Union [AR]", "issue": "2020-04-25T01:31:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-25T01:31:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-25T05:53:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-25T07:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KSHV-SV-A-0147", "wfo": "SHV"}, {"phenomena": "SV", "significance": "A", "eventid": 147, "hvtec_nwsli": null, "area": 61710.0, "locations": "Perry [AR], Cleburne [AR], Desha [AR], Grant [AR], Independence [AR], Pope [AR], Ouachita [AR], Pulaski [AR], Lonoke [AR], Cleveland [AR], Marion [AR], Bradley [AR], Saline [AR], Van Buren [AR], Logan [AR], Monroe [AR], Jackson [AR], Conway [AR], Arkansas [AR], Yell [AR], Boone [AR], Jefferson [AR], Dallas [AR], Prairie [AR], Drew [AR], Lincoln [AR], Calhoun [AR], White [AR], Faulkner [AR], Newton [AR], Woodruff [AR], Searcy [AR], Johnson [AR]", "issue": "2020-04-25T01:31:00Z", "product_issue": "2020-04-25T01:31:00Z", "expire": "2020-04-25T07:00:00Z", "init_expire": "2020-04-25T07:00:00Z", "uri": "/vtec/#2020-O-NEW-KLZK-SV-A-0147", "wfo": "LZK"}
```

I am trying to make it match all the counties so that it'll output just the counties and state in a list like this:

```
Franklin [AL]
Limestone [AL]
Colbert [AL]
Jackson [AL]
Madison [AL]
```

and so on.

The issue I had when I tried using regex was it would match single word counties but not double word counties (such as it'll match Franklin [AL] but only match "Charles" in "St Charles" and leave out the "St")

What's the regex expression I could use to accomplish that? Or alternatively, a sed or awk command?

Comment: Please include your current regex. Do you have a specific reason for not using a language with native JSON support, like Python or Node.js? That might make your life so much easier.

Comment: The regex I have so far is /([\w]+ \[..]) I am not too familiar with Python so am unsure how to start with that

Comment: Check if <the language you're most familiar with> have some tool to process JSON.

Comment: Bash has `jq`, but the work might be easier in some other languages.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
(?<=[\,\"])[^\,\"]+\[[A-Z]{2}\]
```

([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fxhDCN/1))

`(?<=[\,\"])` is a positive lookbehind. It checks to ensure that the target begins with either "," or a quote.

`[^\,\"]+` targets anything not in the lookbehind 0 to unlimited times (the county name).

`\[[A-Z]{2}\]` targets two capital letters encased within brackets (your county abbreviation).

The above expression and demo returns all counties, including "Hot Spring [AR]", "St. Francis [AR]", etc. with no false positives.